# pyDAL - query records newer than a certain date

Tags: sqlite, web2py, pydal

I have the following query working in pure SQL on SQLite but do not know how to convert it to pyDAL:

```
SELECT * FROM buy WHERE date('now','-2 days') < timestamp;
```

The buy table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE "buy"(
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "order_id" CHAR(512),
    "market" CHAR(512),
    "purchase_price" DOUBLE,
    "selling_price" DOUBLE,
    "amount" DOUBLE
, "timestamp" TIMESTAMP, "config_file" CHAR(512));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the SQLite `date` function, you can create the comparison date in Python:

```
import datetime
cutoff_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(2)
rows = db(db.buy.timestamp > cutoff_time).select()
```

Alternatively, you can also pass a raw SQL string as the query:

```
rows = db('buy.timestamp > date("now", "-2 days")').select(db.buy.ALL)
```

Note, in this case, because the query within `db()` is simply a string, the DAL will not know which table is being selected, so it is necessary to explicitly specify the fields in the `.select()` (alternatively, you could add a dummy query that selects all records, such as `(db.buy.id != None)`).